# Character size and spacing/alignment in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I am creating a questionnaire in Microsoft Word 2013 which includes lots of questions and a check box at the end. Since not all characters are the same size the check boxes do not line up, how do I fix that?

What I am looking for is something like a tab stop which will line all check boxes

Answer (score 2):

There are probably several ways of doing it, but I find the easiest is to create a table with the questions in the left column and the abnswers in the right column.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could add a right-justified tab stop and put a tab character between the last word and the check box?

Answer (score 1):

If the check boxes are characters (e.g. character 111 from Windings, ) you can use tabs to align them.

To find the  character, go to Insert > Symbol and click on More Symbols. Then select Wingdings as the font. There are many other tick boxes in the same font, as well as in several others like Webdings.